# Yii 1 Console Application Environment Variables

Tags: php, yii, environment-variables, console-application

For a Yii 1 web application, I am using the `symfony/dotenv` library to read and load environment variables from a .env file. To do this, I added a code in the index.php file,

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; //autoload for composer

if(file_exists('/path/to/.env')){
    $dotenv = new Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv();
    $dotenv->load(__DIR__.'/path/to/.env');
}
else{
   // Missing .env file
   exit;
}
```

This works well with the web application. However, for Yii console applications, this does not work because index.php is not being loaded. Can this be done inside the console.php file? How?

Comment: You can do this the same in `yiic.php`.

Comment: @rob006, it works. I just copied the code I had for the web application (with some minor changes of course). Can you put in your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For console application you can do the same in `protected/yiic.php`. This file is used for bootstrap when you call `./yiic`, in similar way as `index.php` is loaded on web request.